# Retrieving value from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

It's probably too late, and I'm too tired... but I'm trying to check if a value in my SQL is set to 1 or not. And return true if it is. Been a while since I've done SQL so I'm probably just being stupid...

My code is

```
$query   = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT featured FROM al_posts WHERE post_id = {$post_id}");
    if ($query->featured == 1) {
        return true; }
    else {
        return false; }
```

Comment: You need to fetch the result. `$row = $query->fetch_assoc(); if ($row['featured'] == 1) { ...`

Comment: OMG... thank you! I thought it was something like that... I tried to use the [0] on my query.. but that just broke things..... 3am brain ._.

Thanks for the help Nick.

Comment: No worries. Someone has written it up as an answer which is more in line with your code, you should accept that.

Comment: is `$post_id` sanitized?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues):

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You should do:

```
$query = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT featured FROM al_posts WHERE post_id = {$post_id}");
if ($query->fetch_object()->featured == 1) {
    return true; }
else {
    return false; }
```

You can read more about `mysqli_result` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).